# Printing Methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to print the contents of a method (purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies)), but am having no luck. As the following code is written,

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 

public class Store { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Book[] books = readInventory();

        for (Book book : books) {
            System.out.printf("ISBN: %s, Price: %f, Copies: %d%n", book.getISBN(), book.getPrice(), book.getCopies()); 
        }
    String isbn;
    double price;
    int copies;
    purchase(isbn, price, copies);

    }

    public static Book[] readInventory() throws Exception {
        Book[] books = new Book[10];
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("../instr/prog4.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);
        String isbn;
        double price;
        int copies;
        int i = 0;

        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            isbn = fin.next();
                if (fin.hasNextDouble()); {
                    price = fin.nextDouble();
                }
                if (fin.hasNextInt()); {
                    copies = fin.nextInt();
                }
             Book book = new Book(isbn, price, copies);
             books[i] = book;
             i++;
        }
        fin.close();
        return books;
 }

    public static Book[] purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies, Book[] books) {
        int itemsSold = 0;
        double totalMade = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int desiredCopies = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the ISBN number of the book you would like to purchase: ");
            String desiredIsbn = input.next();
            for(int index = 0; index < books.length; index++) {
                if(!books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn))
                    System.out.println("We do not have that book in our inventory.");
                if(books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && copies == 0)
                    System.out.println("That book is currently out of stock.");
                if(books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && copies > 0) {
                    System.out.println("How many copies of this book would you like to purchase?"); 
                        desiredCopies = input.nextInt(); }
                        if(desiredCopies > copies)
                            System.out.println("We only have " + copies + "in stock. Please select another quantity: ");
                            desiredCopies = input.nextInt();
                        // copies = copies - desiredCopies
                        double total = price * desiredCopies;
                    System.out.println("Thank you for your purchase, your order total is: $" + total);
                    itemsSold += desiredCopies;
                    totalMade += total;
                    // update array
                    System.out.print(books[index]);
                    System.out.println("We sold " + itemsSold + " today.");
                    System.out.println("We made $" + totalMade + "today.");
            }   
        return books;
        }

    public void displayInfo(Book[] books) {
        for(int x=0; x<books.length; x++) {
             System.out.println("ISBN: " + books[x].getISBN() + "\n Price: " +
                books[x].getPrice() + "\n Copies: " + books[x].getCopies());
        System.out.print(books[x]);
        }
    }
}

class Book {
 private String isbn;
 private double price;
 private int copies;

 public Book() {
 }

 public Book(String isbnNum, double priceOfBook, int copiesInStock) {
  isbn = isbnNum;
  price = priceOfBook; 
  copies = copiesInStock;
 }

 public String getISBN() {
  return isbn;
 }

 public double getPrice() {
  return price;
 }

 public int getCopies() {
  return copies;
 }

 public void setISBN(String isbn) {
  this.isbn = isbn;
 }

 public void setPrice(double price) {
  this.price = price;
 }

 public void setCopies(int copies) {
  this.copies = copies;
 }

   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ISBN: %s, Price: %f, Copies: %d%n",
            this.getISBN(), this.getPrice(), this.getCopies());
    }

}
```

I get the compiler error

```
Store.java:21: purchase(java.lang.String,double,int,Book[]) in Store cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,double,int)
        purchase(isbn, price, copies);
        ^
1 error
```

If I comment out the:

```
String isbn;
double price;
int copies;
purchase(isbn, price, copies);
```

portion of the main() method, the program prints the array, but nothing else. I need the program to print the purchase method, including the updated array (which I still don't know how to do so any help with that would be appreciated as well).

Any suggestions as to how I can get this to work? I'd like to stick as close to the code I have written if I can, I've been working on this for the last several days but it's due in about an hour and a half so I'm running out of time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `purchase` Method uses a different signature than you are calling.

`purchase` requires `String, double, int, Book[]` as arguments, but you are trying to call it with `String, double, int`. Try adding a Book-Array.

On top of that, looking through `purchase` it looks like most of the arguments are not even being used. You should consider using those arguments or removing them.

PS: You may want to consider using an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ IDEA to help catch such common mistakes :)

Comment: As I'm sure you've gathered by now, I don't know what I'm doing ha. The whole purpose of that particular method is basically to search the array for the book object that matches the ISBN number entered by the user, look at the number of copies of that particular book to see if the quantity they entered is possible or if the book is even in stock, etc. So would all of that be possible without passing it anything and just having it as public static Book[] purchas() {?

Comment: Yes, it is! You are already reading input from the user with `Scanner.next()` and since the other values are stored within the Book, there is no need (or indeed way) to give those values to `purchase(Book[] books)`. Just make sure that instead of `copies`you check against `Book.getCopies()`, etc.

Comment: Ok, I've gone through and done as you suggested, but now I'm getting all these compiler errors dealing with "non-static variable copies cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Check what all you have declared as `static`. Generally you should not declare anything `static` that does not need to be. In this case, only `main(), readInventory(), purchase(),` and `displayInfo()` need to be static, going by the code in your question. Generally speaking, the only time something should be declared static is when you need to call it outside of an Object.

Comment: I went back and made sure those were the only methods I had set to static, but I'm still getting the errors such as "Store.java:73: non-static method getPrice() cannot be referenced from a static context
double total = Book.getPrice() * desiredCopies;"

Comment: I don't really understand when and when not to declare methods as static, so that's been giving me grief too.

Comment: Ah, that code snipped shows the problem :) You are trying to call `Book.getPrice()`, but what you really should call is something like `books[index].getPrice()`. You need to call the method from an Object, while you were calling it from the class. This can be pretty confusing at first, I agree, but once you get the hang of it, it's not very difficult. Perhaps this can help clear up some confusion: http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/

Comment: Ok, that fixed those, now there's just one remaining error "Store.java:72: unexpected type
required: variable
found   : value
                                                        books[index].getCopies() = books[index].getCopies() - desiredCopies;"

Comment: If you want to change a variable inside of an object, you can't use a getter method. Instead use the setter method: `books[index].setCopies(books[index].getCopies() - desiredCopies);` I will again suggest that you try using an IDE as I mentioned in my answer, as it will help you greatly spotting these problems :)

Comment: Oh, and please don't forget to select an answer as correct if it helped you!

Comment: Ok so I'm still trying to get this to work. on that particular portion of code, I had books[index].getCopies = ... I understand what you suggested about changing a variable inside an object, but am having trouble figuring out what would go on the left of that equals sign?

Comment: You do not need the equals sign. `setCopies()` already does that.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is because you passed three arguments, when the method requires four. The following code would compile:

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies, books);
```

**However**, your code looks wrong in other ways, since you've assigned no values to `isbn`, `price` or `copies`. Your `Book`class already contains theses values, so you only need to supply an array of `Book` objects to your print method.

E.g. change your purchase method to:

```
public static Book[] purchase(Book[] books) {
  int itemsSold = 0;
  double totalMade = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int desiredCopies = 0;

  System.out
      .println("Please enter the ISBN number of the book you would like to purchase: ");
  String desiredIsbn = input.next();
  for (int index = 0; index < books.length; index++) {
    if (!books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn))
      System.out.println("We do not have that book in our inventory.");
    if (books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && books[index].getCopies() == 0)
      System.out.println("That book is currently out of stock.");
    if (books[index].getISBN().equals(desiredIsbn) && books[index].getCopies() > 0) {
      System.out
          .println("How many copies of this book would you like to purchase?");
      desiredCopies = input.nextInt();
    }
    if (desiredCopies > books[index].getCopies())
      System.out.println("We only have " + books[index].getCopies()
          + "in stock. Please select another quantity: ");
    desiredCopies = input.nextInt();
    // copies = copies - desiredCopies
    double total = books[index].getPrice() * desiredCopies;
    System.out.println("Thank you for your purchase, your order total is: $"
        + total);
    itemsSold += desiredCopies;
    totalMade += total;
    // update array
    System.out.print(books[index]);
    System.out.println("We sold " + itemsSold + " today.");
    System.out.println("We made $" + totalMade + "today.");
  }
  return books;
}
```

Some other notes:

- Try a for-each loop, e.g. `for (Book book : books) {`
- Consider using a currency type rather than a `double`.
- Don't declare variables before you need them.

Comment: First of all I feel really stupid lol. Anyway, that's another thing that's throwing me off is that these variables aren't actually given values until the getter and setter methods in the Book class. If I comment them out of the main method I get errors saying the symbols aren't found, but if I leave them in it says they haven't been initialized.

Comment: @BethTanner See above edits. You should remove the arguments completely.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong number of arguments in your `purchase()` method.
You have declared it something like

> `public Book[] purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies, Book[]
>   books)//taking four arguments`

i.e with four arguments,but you are passing only three while calling it i.e

> `purchase(isbn, price, copies);//but you are calling it by passing only three parameters reason for the error`

Answer (score 0):

In this line is a parameter missing:

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies);
```

Think you have to add books as parameter

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies, books);
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling:

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies);
```

Purchase() is defined as

```
public Book[] purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies, Book[] books)
```

Perhaps you meant to call:

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies, books);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `Book` array in your method. Pass `Book[] books` as the last argument in the `purchase()` method like :

```
purchase(isbn, price, copies, books);
```

However, how do you call `purchase()` method in your main method, since it is `non-static`

```
public Book[] purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies, Book[] books) {....}
```

Comment: I didn't think about that until I got a compiler error stating that, so I changed the purchase method to static.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 3 arguments for your purchase method as follows
 purchase(isbn, price, copies);

But There are 4 parameters for purchase method as follows:
public Book[] purchase(String isbn, double price, int copies, Book[] books)

So you need to pass 4th variable 'books'. Thats why you are getting compiler error.